# Best Backup System for Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, backup, clonezilla

Is Clonezilla the best backup system for Ubuntu 12.04.5? And if so, what do I need to do to download it...ie: Do I need to partition files? If so, how to do this. Thanks.

Comment: You could try this question: [Comparison of backup tools](http://askubuntu.com/q/2596/178596)

Comment: flagging this too broad

Answer (score 0):

Backups is kind of complicated, because everybody has different needs.

Clonezilla is an option, as you mentioned, but for a desktop system something lighter like Duplicity or Deja-Dup might be a better fit, as smaller, incrimental backups can be stored on a remote server or an external drive.

Tarsnap is a lighter, secure alternative.

If you've got multiple systems in your environement, something like Bacula might also be useful, but requires a much more complicated setup.

Comment: Thank you K. Daien Freeheart. I'm going with Clonezilla after researching all of your suggestions.

Comment: Note: Dega-Dup seems to work fine for /home, but so far fails to backup protected system files.  People suggest sudo deja-dup --backup but that can't find my plug in USB drive.